# Power supply for remote load

Tags: power-supply, transistors, circuit-design, resistance, load

I tried to design power supply circuit myself because no power supply would do for me (or I'm just unaware). My issue is that I have power supply far away from load and there is no way I can shorten the distance. The load is variable from 5 W to 30 W and requires constant 5.1 V, but the cable has some resistance and when the load gets to its max there isn't sufficient voltage for its function. So my idea was to create step down power supply with constant voltage and somehow increase output voltage with increasing power demand so at the end of the cable voltage will be stable 5.1 V.

[image: circuit I tried to create]

My idea was to use two potentiometers to set base voltage and how much the voltage has to rise with rising power demand.

I created this so I would appreciate any feedback or constructive judgement (with explanation why) on this circuit. I'm aware I should add capacitors to op amps to stabilize them but I don't know how. Or if you have better idea for that supply please share it with me because I'm no electrical engineer -- I can't just do it myself.

I understand there are power sensing premade PSUs but the wiring can't be changed. I need to adjust it afterwards. The wiring looks like a tree, and branches don't have same length.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site. If you browse around for a bit, you may notice that no questions are titled in the manner you've titled this one. Please edit your title so that you are describing your problem briefly. Avoid using "text speak" abbreviations like 'pls' and 'idk' - they are unprofessional and often unclear.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention before answering, the question should be more general to help more people.

Comment: the wiring sketch is just illustrative I forgot one more branch

Comment: Get thicker wire so you don't lose so much voltage running that distance.  If you can't find thick wire, several pieces of thinner wire in parallel is just as good.

Comment: I have to comment that it should actually be possible to add more wires from the supply to the load so that remote sensing can be used. To simply say that you cannot change the wiring going will hold you back with a more complicated and less reliable circuits. Add the wires even if you have to zip tie them along the existing wiring harness.

Answer (score 6):

> I tried to design power supply circuit myself cuz no power supply would do for me

> My issue is that I have power supply far away from load and there is no way I can shorten the distance

Last thing you want to be doing is designing your own power supply for this. Buy a 5V power supply that has *remote sensing* terminals. But ensure that the supply has enough voltage headroom. If the wire resistance is excessive, then the supply may in fact not be able to output a high-enough voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fH8dDm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now, if you want to play with a design, then sure, one could put something together - but not for a power supply for actual use, where the output is protected in various ways, hardened against ESD, and - most importantly - *compensated* in spite of variable load - that requires actual work :) The below is **only a sketch**.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQE6FK.png)</sup>

This supply requires C3 to be 1000uF and have ESR>0.2Ω. Larger capacitors will need even higher ESR - you'd have to add a series resistor to raise its ESR. When the ESR is too low, the supply will oscillate.

Q1 converts the reference voltage to a current. Q2 is a current source loading the Zener diode. R9 provides a bootstrap load to the Zener. Adjust R6 so that the Zener diode has about 50mA flowing across it.

OA2-M1-R10 generate a current proportional to the load current. R4 then converts that current into a voltage, effectively adding it to the Zener voltage.

M2 is a series NMOS pass element, controlled by OA1.

The lowest input voltage is limited to about 6.5-7V by the M2 threshold voltage and OA1's output voltage range.

Do note that M2 dissipates **lots** of power if the input voltages are high. It depends on the wire resistance, but the lowest input voltage that keeps the output in regulation should be used, plus a margin of about 0.5V.

This supply has no current limit: the current limiting should be provided by the supply feeding the input of this one.

**The idea of using 12V as the input voltage is nice until you try to run the circuit and burn a hole in the table.**  The pass element will be dissipating as much power as a soldering iron, and will be almost just as hot! You can of course do it, but it will take a rather big heatsink.

Comment: Pretty much that's the standard. I have a box full of some made by International Power. Probably many other suppliers of same. +1

Comment: Thanks I had no idea such circuits exists. but not sure if it will do since the wiring is not that simple its already done and it looks like tree at the load end and each branch is different lenght thats why I wanted it to be adjustable.

Comment: "Last thing you want to be doing is designing your own power supply for this." May I ask why? I get that Im not qualified but what am I supposet to do when I have problem to witch I dont know the solution.

Comment: @Creo The 2nd diagram that shows the R1 next to the power supply is the one you want then. Only two wires going to the load, and R1 can be adjusted to match the wire resistance. The power supply itself has a potentiometer to trim the voltage, so a 5V supply will easily provide 5.1V + some wire drop (up to 1-1.5V).

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica Maybe I'm getting old and senile, but how does your second diagram with R1 work? The sense terminals still maintain Vprog across the PSU end of the feeder. Force+ rises above Sense+ sure, but that doesn't do anything to the load voltage, which still drops below Vprog by the drop of the feeder wires. Can you write me an equation, or drop a link to an App-note where its operation is described?

Comment: @Neil_UK Nah, it’s just me answering stuff in the middle of the night. There’s a bit more to this trick it looks like.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica what do you reckon to my attempt? It looks complicated, but I'm not sure it could be any simpler. My first attempt replaced Q1+R2 with a resistor equal to R1, and doubled Rcomp. The compensation maths works out, but you're left with a large difference between force+ and sense+ which most supplies won't tolerate.

Comment: @Neil_UK Put it together and see how well it works :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think an op-amp with with 5.1v voltage reference or 1.25v and respective gain on the non-inverting input and wiring the inverting input to where you want the voltage to be 5.1v and darlington pair on the output of the op-amp with another power source will make the voltage stable at 5.1v but the power source and the transistor should be able to handle the current.

Comment: Sorry Im lost but if you suggesting to add more wires then I cant.

Answer (score 0):

If a load needs to be far from the power supply and remain well regulated, what's usually done is to use remote sensing.

You disconnect the connections that sense the voltage at the power supply output and run them through separate wires so that they connect right at the load.

This puts the wires feeding the load into the feedback loop so their resistive drop is accounted for.

Since you have multiple branches of different lengths you have several options:

1. If you have a long run of wire that branches at the end you could connect the remote sensing at the farthest point just before the branches. If the branches are long you would still have voltage drops in them, and if they are different lengths the drops will be different.
2. You can try to sense the current and adjust the output of the supply to compensate for the cable loss (what you appear to be trying to do). If there are long branches of different lengths you will have the same problem as in #1, different branches will have different voltages.
3. If you need tight regulation and have long branches with different lengths you would need to move the regulation to the load end of the cables. Put a regulator at each load and feed them through the cables with at least enough voltage to satisfy the input requirements of the regulators plus whatever cable loss you have.

If the loads are divided pretty evenly that's max 30 W divided 5 ways at 5.1 V each, so a little over an amp each. Get 5 switching regulators good for a couple of amps each, put one at the end of each branch of the cable, and feed the cable with your 12 volts.

If the branches are short enough that they won't have much loss you could use one switching regulator that will handle the max current at the point where they branch.

Comment: I cant add additional wiring. Thats why I came up with this.

Comment: It will be a circuit at the end of the wires that will add the missing voltage, if this option is viable I will elaborate with a drawn circuit

Comment: there is no simple end. you may missed the edit.

Comment: @Creo Okay, I've amended my answer.

Comment: @Creo  If this doesn't work for you you'll need to give us a detailed diagram of the wiring with the length of each run and what gauge they are, and what the maximum current each load with draw is. Then we can maybe figure out what the voltage drops will be and see what solution is workable.

Comment: to your second point. yes I was trying to do so. difference of branch lengths ate in 1.5m to proportion of whole thing that goes for roughly 17m

Comment: and to psu at end/start of each branch. the cables are moving in carousel and even the blob when branching start is enough to cause issues on its own

Answer (score 0):

Taking my inspiration from Kuba's attempt, here's my take on using a 4-wire power supply for remote voltage drop compensation. Rcomp = Rleads.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXlEyd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Q1+Q2 form a voltage transfer circuit from V(R2) to V(R1) with gain R1/R2, here shown as unity. Rbias is used to pass a small current through the diode-connected Q2, to set up a VBE offset on the bases. The emitters will be at nominally equal voltages, so a voltage difference between sense- and force- will appear across R2, forcing a current through Q1. This current passes through R1, setting up a voltage difference between force+ and sense+.

Start at zero current. There is no IR drop across either the lead resistance Rleads, or the compensating resistance Rcomp. R2 has essentially zero volts across it, therefore so does R1. The sense terminals monitor the load voltage, and the output voltage is correct.

Now allow the load to take a significant current. There is a voltage drop on Rleads, and the same drop on Rcomp. This drop then appears across R1, depressing the sense+ voltage with respect to the force+ voltage, which has to rise to maintain regulation. This rise compensates for the voltage drop across Rleads.

R1/2 have nominal values at the moment. Depending on the input impedance of the sense terminals, they could be made larger. The power supply should give some indication of the maximum resistance allowed here.

Note that some supplies restrict the maximum voltage drop allowed between force and sense terminals, often to a diode drop or two, so there may be a limit to the size of Rleads that can be compensated for.

There are two aspects to stability - DC and RF.

DC. This network gives the power supply an effective negative output resistance. As long as Rload+Rleads > Rcomp, it should always settle to a single valid operating point. This might not be the case if Rcomp ever went open circuit, for instance by trying to make it adjustable. If you do want to adjust the output resistance of the circuit, do it by changing the value of R2, so that the correction goes to zero if the wiper leaves the track, not Rcomp or R1.

RF. These components will cause extra phase shift in the feedback loop. This is where a discrete transistor Q1 used in common base with lowish values for R1/2 should be very fast, and so superior to a slow op-amp alternative.